# Display servlet response in the same jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, response, html

I have a servlet and a jsp page which shows the result of a .txt file (which is on my local machine)on the jsp page. My problem is when I click the VIEWLOG button on the jsp page it should show me the result on the same page. For example my VIEWLOG button is on a page called view.jsp, I should see the log on

```
http://localhost:8080/Project/view.jsp
```

But it is displaying the result in the following url

```
http://localhost:8080/project/status?showstatus=Status
```

. Any idea how can I get the result on the same page where VIEWLOG button is. Below is the code snippet.

Servlet:

```
public class Status extends HttpServlet {
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws 
IOException {

        try {
            PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
            File file = new File("C:\\Debug\\logfile.txt");
            if (file.exists()) {
              BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
              String line = "";
              while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                   out.println(line);
              }
            }
        } catch (Throwable t)  {  
            t.printStackTrace();  
        }  finally {}  

    }
}
```

JSP:

```
<div id= "log" style="display:none;">
<FORM action="logfile" METHOD="GET">
    <input type=submit 
           name=showLog 
           id=txtSubmit 
           value=ViewLOG />
    </FORM>
</div>
```

WEB.XML:

```
<servlet>       
    <servlet-name>LogFile</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.san.plc.LogFile</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LogFile</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/logfile</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: When you have a form that does a GET that means the parameters get put in the url. Change it to a POST and that should fix the problem. Also, make sure you're forwarding instead of redirecting in your servlet. That will keep the URL the same. This is just advice, I can't follow what's going on in your code from what you've shown.

Comment: @tieTYT: If am using POST it says HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
What my code is doing is I have a text file in my local machine. I want to show this text file on a web page. ie when I click a button on the webpage to view the text file it should be displayed on the same webpage

Comment: That's probably because your servlet isn't implementing a doPost?

Comment: i did modified my above code with doPost and method=POST in jsp, then it started giving me 405 error.

Comment: And you stopped and started the webapp after recompiling the servlet to use post?

Comment: @developerwjk :oh yeah after implementing a doPost and starting and stopping the webabb did work but its still not displaying the result on the same page instead its showing the result in http://localhost:8080/ELicensing/logfile where logfile is the form action but i want the result in http://localhost:8080/ELicensing/view.jsp

Comment: Can some one please help with the above question